# How to Find Certain Characters When They Are Not Part of a String? (Regex, Python)

Tags: python, regex

I started with `inp = re.sub('[^A-Z]', '', inp)`, but realized that removes `val = 0`, but I want to not remove `val = 0` at the beginning of the string, while removing all non-uppercase-alphabetic characters in other cases. How do I do that?

Comment: What is `inp` and what is expected output? What are actual requirements?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but for the love of God write `[^A-Z]` instead of `[^ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]`.

Comment: `inp` is something typed in by the user, input. The expected output is removing all characters that are not uppercase letters except for `val = 0` at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Okay, I fixed that. I still don't know how to achieve the above.

Comment: Still not clear, try [`re.sub(r'(^val = 0)|[^A-Za-z]', lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else "", inp)`](http://ideone.com/2njT8D) - but this will also remove spaces. Add `\s` to the the `[^A-Z]` (`[^A-Z\s]`) to avoid that.

Comment: That's OK, I want spaces to be removed.

Comment: Do you *know* that the beginning of the string is `val = 0`?  In that case you could just apply your regexp on the rest: `inp = inp[:7] + re.sub('[^A-Z]', '', inp[7:])`

Comment: "val = 0" is a literal string?

Comment: Yes, the Python code is evaluated. @Alfe, I will try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This solution is for cases when the substring to protect at the beginning is not known**.

To "protect" a specific substring at the beginning of the string and remove some characters everywhere else, you need to specify an *alternation* in the pattern where the part that you want to keep is enclosed with a capturing group. Then, during the replacement, you just need to check if the captured group matched, and if yes, just restore the value in the result. Else, replace with an empty string.

```
import re
inp = "val = 20 MORE @#$TEXT.!!??"
res = re.sub(r'(^val\s*=\s*\d+)|[^A-Z]', lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else "", inp)
print(res)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/2njT8D)

Pattern breakdown:

- `(^val\s*=\s*\d+)` - `val` followed with 0+ whitespace symbols (`\s*`) followed with a `=` followed with 0+ whitespace symbols followed with 1+ digits (`\d+`) at the beginning of the string (`^`)
- `|` - or
- `[^A-Z]` - any non-uppercase-alphabetic characters

**NOTE** If you need to replace all non-alpha characters, use `[A-Za-z]` or add a `flags=re.I` to the regex definition.

Comment: When did the `[^A-Z]` become a `[^A-Za-z]`?  Am I missing something?

Comment: I saw someone do that, it is probably a mistake. The input should be uppercase, and lowercase should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions describe expressions of a regular language.  Without going into theoretical details about context-free languages, in general the abilities of regexps are limited in some aspects.  You ask for a regular expression which means (more or less) "a non-capital-letter character which is not part of a special part at the beginning".  In general, this is not "expressable" with regexp alone (and in your special case in which the "part at the beginning" seems to be complex, also not).

I propose to do what you want in two steps:

1. Split the input into the beginning part (`val = 0`) and the rest.  In case the beginning part does not exist, take the whole input as rest.
2. Apply your change to the rest alone.

Then you can easily concatenate the two parts and are done.

A solution for this could be:

```
# step 1:
match = re.match('^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]* = [0-9]+', inp)
if match:
    beginning = match.group()
    rest = inp[match.end():]
else:
    beginning = ''
    rest = inp
# step 2:
return beginning + re.sub('[^A-Z]', '', rest)
```

Comment: This works, but someone commented with an answer that uses only one `re.sub()` and nothing else, one Regex algorithm, for lack of better words.

Comment: You have to decide which you find more readable ;-)

Comment: @asherdrummond, I think I found another approach which is even fancier.  See my other answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I quickly finished this project! I thought the whole thing might take a week, but it was closer to a day...

Answer (score 0):

If you can *invert* your second character group (which in your case seems to be an option by simply exchanging it with `[A-Z]`), you can simply find all parts you want to keep instead:

```
inp = 'val = 20 FooBar'
return ''.join(re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]* = [0-9]+|[A-Z]', inp))
```

Will return `'val = 20FB'`.